# Weird not supported operation error in simple loop over dataframe

Tags: python

I work on a dataframe and I want to iterate over one column as I did this hundreds of times with many dataframes. Today I get an error and I can't wrap my head around what's wrong with it.
Maybe worth mentioning, the dataframe is a concatenation.

```
log = (pd.concat([log_entry,log_exit]).sort_values(by=['date']))
```

dataframe:

```
                    position order  price       PnL
date                
2022-03-27 20:45:00 short   entry   29.242291   0
2022-03-28 13:45:00 short   entry   31.052375   0
2022-03-28 15:00:00 short   entry   31.072893   0
2022-03-28 19:15:00 short   entry   31.070073   0
2022-03-28 20:45:00 short   entry   31.220069   0
2022-03-28 23:00:00 -          TP   30.016500   0
2022-03-28 23:15:00 -          TP   29.788000   0
2022-03-28 23:15:00 -          TP   29.820500   0
2022-03-28 23:30:00 -          TP   29.640500   0
2022-03-29 05:30:00 short   entry   30.902677   0
2022-03-29 06:15:00 short   entry   30.893078   0
```

iteration:

```
for i in range(len(log.index)):
    if log.position[i] == 'short':
            print('ok')
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-c8832d66a85a> in <module>
    156 
    157 for i in range(len(log.index)):
--> 158     if log.position[i] == 'short':
    159             print('ok')
    160 #         dd_buffer.append(log.price[i])

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1066         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1067         try:
-> 1068             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1069 
   1070             if not is_scalar(result):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4748             # python 3
   4749             if is_scalar(key):  # pragma: no cover
-> 4750                 raise IndexError(key)
   4751             raise InvalidIndexError(key)
   4752 

IndexError: 0
```

How is this possible??

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Looping over a DataFrame is rarely a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `log.position[i]` you are matching the *index* of the dataframe, i.e. the datetimes. There is no index 0 (only datetimes), that's why you get the IndexError. Use `log.position.iloc[i]` instead for integer-location based indexing for selection by position.

Comment: Still don't get why it usually always works and not now. In the same project with another df I use ´for i in range(len(df.index)): if df.position[i] == "short"´ works fine

Comment: Maybe the datetime wasn't the index there but a column instead

Comment: I always use date time as index. But anyway it's just an integer iterator using range(len()). actually it doesn't matter what the index is

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I think I understand your question now:
You iterate over the range(len(index))
which will always start at 0 and iterate until len(index)-1

your Index doesn't have to be a sequential order, you could for example remove your index=0 and then your index would start at 1 (you could view it as another column which can simply be edited)

Try:

```
for i in log.index:
    print(i)
```

This should show that your index doesn't start at 0 if I'm correct.

```
for i in log.index:
    if log.position.iloc[i] == "short":
        print("ok")
```

That should do what you wanted.

Earlier answer(
I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve,
but it looks like you want to know how many "short" are in position

Try:
log.position.value_counts()

to see how many of each value are in there

Normally there are better ways than to loop over a dataframe in pandas)

Comment: No I don't want this. It's not about what happens later in the loop, only why the iteration doesn't work

Comment: I saw your other comment, but can't answer on it due to insufficient reputation. Have you checked how your index looks like? it doesn't have to be 0,1,2,3 but could be 1000, 10001, 10003 and so on, you iterate over the len(index), which would always start at 0. Try for i in log.index